# I want to throw a user defined exception for empty json in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, if-statement, input

I want to check if the the input json is present or not and return a message accordingly. There are two methods to verify this, using isset($a) method or using $request->has('a') method. But whichever method I use if my input json is null it gives an exception "Undefined property: stdClass::$a".

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));
    $a = $input->a;

if(isset($a)){
         $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>200, "response_message"=>"Input present"));
             return $response; 
      } else {
       $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>150, "response_message"=>"Input absent"));
    return $response; 
                    }
```

Input json: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens on this line in your code

```
$a = $input->a;
```

Which is before the isset($a) check.
Try rewriting it like this:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));

if(isset($input->a)){
    $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>200, "response_message"=>"Input present"));
    return $response;
} else {
    $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>150, "response_message"=>"Input absent"));
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped. Is there any way to do this for many user inputs?
eg: What if I have following inputs: a,b,c,d,e,f. So in this case is there any other way or I have to run if case for each and every input ?

Comment: You might try the $request->filled() method. So instead of "if(isset($input->a)){" try "if($request->filled(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])){".